# Las varibles $_POST no estan definidas tras consulta con metodo ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, formdata

Estoy teniendo un problema al utilizar objetos "FormData", sucede que al enviar los datos con el metodo ajax (de jquery) las variables $_POST no estan definidas en el archivo .php; sinceramente no se donde esta la falla, por que al pasar un json todo funciona con normalidad.

Codigo Javascript:

```
$( "body" ).on("click","#boton_guardar_cambios_entrada",function(e){

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('autor','Chris');   


     $.ajax(
     {
        url: "editar_entrada.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(json){
            alert(json.hello);

        }});//fin de ajax   
   });
```

Y en el fichero "editar_entrada.php":

```
<?php

  $jsondata = array();
  $autor=$_POST['autor'];
  $jsondata["hello"]=$autor;
  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

?>
```

Comment: Puedes probar seteando `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` también.

Comment: Gracias amigo @MarioL por tu respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: cuando le das un print_r($_POST);exit(); que te muestra?

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta, me sale  "Array()".

Comment: Cuando pruebo una expresión como la siguiente:  $autor=isset($_POST['autor']) ? $_POST['autor'] : "No esta definida";           Siempre me da "false" osea "No esta definida".

Comment: OK , trata de colocar tu ajax asi:  `$.ajax({
                                          url: 'editar_entrada.php',
                                          type: 'POST',
                                         dataType: 'json',
                                                       data: data,
                                                       success: function(json){`

Comment: Ya solucione el problema amigos. El problema era que incluía 2 versiones distintas de jquery. Cuando borre la más antigua comenzó a funcionar. Gracias a todos por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

dentro de tu funcion principal puedes intentar con esto

```
const postData = {author:'Chris'};

$.post(url,postData,function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```